# Cannot run eth.getCompilers() in Geth

Tags: ethereum

I am playing around with Geth and ethereum, and trying to install solc. I tried `npm install solc` as well as `brew install solidity` - the first one worked, and the second one was hung. Anyway, when I fire up my Geth console in mac OSX and try to run `eth.getCompilers()`, I keep getting the following error:

```
Error: The method eth_getCompilers does not exist/is not available
at web3.js:3104:20
at web3.js:6191:15
at web3.js:5004:36
at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Please help?

Thanks,
Laura

Answer (score 1):

Method eth.getComilers() has gone in Ethereum 1.6.0. Check this out: 
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/3793